# How to execute Future payments (Paypal REST IOS API) on server-side (using Php curl)

Tags: php, ios, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**I have access_token, corelation id and amount.**
 *Please provide solution in CURL php.*
GIT  Url
       https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment' \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: c2edbd6e97b14ff2b19ddb8eec9d264c" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer WfXdnxmyJtdF4q59ofxuQuAAk6eEV-Njm6puht3Nk3w" \
        -d '{
               "intent":"authorize",
               "payer":{
                  "payment_method":"paypal"
               },
               "transactions":[
                  {
                     "amount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "total":"1.88"
                     },
                     "description":"future of sauces"
                  }
               ]
            }'

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: 10aab1a2e941462096ca8aba539784f3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Authorization: Bearer A103.Ekl88t1fnvoypD1F7HZDt3X-jzmxm6rxMxW6QtI79iIJdgDaDiIO8luWS-C1D-0z.h2YAz4LujULmTjQXcPjF8_ImbV0");
    curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
           "intent":"authorize",
           "payer":{
              "payment_method":"paypal"
           },
           "transactions":[
              {
                 "amount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "total":"1.88"
                 },
                 "description":"future of sauces"
              }
           ]
        }');

**using curl Php**

    $result1 = curl_exec($ch);
    $information = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result1);
    print_r($information);die;
```

Return curl info 
1Array
(
    [url] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 401
    [header_size] => 520
    [request_size] => 514
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.542536
    [namelookup_time] => 0.341438
    [connect_time] => 0.628821
    [pretransfer_time] => 1.237494
    [size_upload] => 363
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 235
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 363
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.542478
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 173.0.82.78
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

```
[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 115.112.59.164
[local_port] => 58225
[request_header] => POST /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1
```

Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 363
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, this code has problems with the HTTP headers you want to send.

`CURLOPT_HEADER`, when set to `true`, will cause the HTTP response headers to be included in the cURL response.

To send HTTP headers, you need to use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and pass an array of headers.

It would look like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id: 10aab1a2e941462096ca8aba539784f3',
    'Authorization: Bearer A103.Ekl88t1fnvoypD1F7HZDt3X-jzmxm6rxMxW6QtI79iIJdgDaDiIO8luWS-C1D-0z.h2YAz4LujULmTjQXcPjF8_ImbV0',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

You'll also need to call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` to actually send a POST request.